# Prevent Windows 2008 Server from polluting BIND

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, bind

We have a Windows 2008 Server running as DC. DNS is provided by a standalone machine running ISC BIND v9. The zone is configured to accept dynamic updates from the Windows machine. This is needed - the DC needs to update resource records in the zone.

This is all working well, the windows machine registers all necessary resource records in the BIND zone. But - it also registers the IP-Adresses of all non-localhost Interfaces as A Record for the whole zone, which interferes with other services.

Assuming the server has three interfaces with IP-Adresses IPA, IPB and IPC. Without dynamic updates the zone will have a single (added by hand) 'A' record:

```
domain.com IN A SOMEIP
```

This is the desired state.

With dynamic  updates the zone will have four 'A' records:

```
domain.com IN A SOMEIP
domain.com IN A IPA
domain.com IN A IPB
domain.com IN A IPC
```

How can we setup the Windows or BIND Machine to keep dynamic updates while avoiding this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per default, Windows tries to register the IPs of every network connection on the DNS server. To prevent this follow this procedure:

- Open the properties of the network connection which should not be registered at the DNS server.
- Select "*TCP/IPv4*"
- Click "*Properties*"
- Click "*Advanced*"
- Select "*DNS*"
- Uncheck "*Register this connection's addresses in DNS*"

Do this for every NIC you don't want in your DNS.